# how to get & replace IMG attributes from VAR, via JS

Tags: javascript, image, replace

how to get conditionally IMG attributes like SRC, ALT, HEIGHT, WEIGHT from INPUT VAR HTML
and than perform a in place replacement, so that only IMG tags are affected, and the rest of HTML should remain intact...

how could i do this in js/jquery... ?

CONDITION

```
if images->getAttribute('width') > 18 && images->getAttribute('width')< 640)
```

INPUT:

```
html='<p>some text</p>
<p><img src="image_1.jpg" width="630" height="380" alt="image_1"></p>
<p>some more text</p>
<p><img src="image_2.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="image_2"></p>';
```

OUTPUT:

```
html='<p>some text</p>
<p><a class="test" title="image_1" href="image_1.jpg" rel="image_1">
<img width="630" height="380" alt="" src="image1.jpg" ></a></p>
<p>some more text</p>
<p><img src="image_2.jpg" alt="image 2" width="18" height="18"></p>';
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you even know how to program Javascript? It doesn't use `->` notation for objects, it uses `.`.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match the question. You said you wanted to modify `IMG` tags, why did you add an `A` tag.

Comment: Barmar that -> is from a php Snippet, It had worked on this task, I used it just as an example. yep the A tags is needed for a script to work. ;-) thanks for you reply ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that (using jquery) :

```
$html = $(html);

//For each img in html
$html.find('img').each(function() {
    $img = $(this);

    //Your own logic
    if ($img->attr('width') > 18 && $img->attr('width') < 640) {
        //We create our a link
        $a = $('<a class="test" title="' 
            + $img.attr('title') + '" alt="' 
            + $img.attr('title') + '" href="' 
            + $img.attr('src') + '"></a>');

        //We add a cone of the original image into our a
        $a.append($img.clone());
    }

    //We replace our image by our a link
    $img.replaceWith($a);
});

//We get the new html string
html = $html.html();
```